# D3 cluster design layout click function to open and close node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am trying to design a rotating cluster layout,want to open one parent at a time,the problem is in click function wen i tried something like this

```
       function click(d)
     if(d.parent)
       {
   d3.select("text").style("stroke","red");

           }

 if(!d.children)
data.children.forEach(collapse);
  if (d.children) {
d._children = d.children;
d.children = null;
} else {
d.children = d._children;
     d._children = null;
          }
```

it opens the node,but not able to close and the opened childrens are very close to the parent text

here is my complete code

```
<head>
  <title>Radial Cluster Demo</title>
  <script src="ddd.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <style>
  .node {
    cursor: pointer;
    }

  .overlay {
    background-color: white;
  }

  .node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  .node text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
  }

  .link {
    fill: none;
  }
</style>
 </head>

 <body>

   <div id="tree-container"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  myJSON = {
    "name": "அகல்",
    "children": [{
      "name": "விலகு",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "நீங்கு",
      "color": "red",
      "l": "red",
      "f": "360",
      "t": "நீங்குதல், பாயிருளகல (புறநா.25).",
      "children": [{
        "name": "விலகு",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "பின்னிடு",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "ஒதுங்கு",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "இடம்விட்டுப் பெயர்",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "பிரி",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "பின்வாங்கு",
        "color": "red"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "பிரி",
      "color": "red",
      "t": "பிரிதல். அகன்ற பூங்கொடியை (பாரத.குரு.79)"
    }, {
      "name": "கட",
      "color": "#1E90FF",
      "t": "கடத்தல். (திவா.)"
    }, {
      "name": "விருத்தியடை",
      "color": "green",
      "t": "விருத்தியடைதல் (குறள்,170.)"
    }, {
      "name": "விசாலி",
      "color": "#00C957",
      "t": "விசாலித்தல். (புறநா.3,16.)"
    }, {
      "name": "நீட்டு",
      "color": "#00C957"
    }, {
      "name": "விரி",
      "color": "#00C957"
    }, {
      "name": "பரப்பு",
      "color": "#00C957"
    }, {
      "name": "விரிவு",
      "color": "#00C957"
    }, {
      "name": "விளக்குத் தகழி",
      "color": "#D15FEE",
      "t": "விளக்குத் தகழி. திருவிளக்குத் திரியிட்டங் ககல்பரப்பி (பெரியபு.கலிய.15)."
    }, {
      "name": "சட்டி",
      "color": "orange",
      "l": "red",
      "f": "360",
      "t": "சட்டி. காரகற்கூவியன் (பெரும்பாண். 377)",
      "children": [{
        "name": "மட்பாண்டம்",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "உலோகத்தட்டு",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "திதி",
        "color": "green"
      }, {
        "name": "அறுபது",
        "color": "orange"
      }, {
        "name": "தாமரை",
        "color": "purple"
      }, {
        "name": "அழித்தல்",
        "color": "brown"
      }, {
        "name": "கொல்லுதல்",
        "color": "brown"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "ஓர் அளவு",
      "color": "blue",
      "t": "ஓர் அளவு. (தொல்.எழுத்.170,உரை.)"
    }, {
      "name": "வெள்வேல்",
      "color": "maroon",
      "t": "(சங்.அக.)"
    }, {
      "name": "உள்ளூர்",
      "color": "purple",
      "t": "(பொதி. நி.) "
    }, {
      "name": "ஊரின் உட்புறம்",
      "color": "purple",
      "t": "ஊரின் உட்புறம். (பொதி. நி.)"
    }, {
      "name": "நாடு",
      "color": "brown",
      "l": "red",
      "f": "360",
      "t": "நாடு. (பொதி. நி.)",
      "children": [{
        "name": "தேடு",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "ஆராய்",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "தெரி",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "அள",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "கிட்டு",
        "color": "red"
      }, {
        "name": "விரும்பு",
        "color": "green"
      }, {
        "name": "நினை",
        "color": "green"
      }, {
        "name": "மோப்பம்பிடி",
        "color": "green"
      }, {
        "name": "தேசம்",
        "color": "purple"
      }, {
        "name": "இடம்",
        "color": "purple"
      }, {
        "name": "பூமி",
        "color": "purple"
      }, {
        "name": "இராச்சியம்",
        "color": "purple"
      }, {
        "name": "நாட்டுப்புறம்",
        "color": "purple"
      }, {
        "name": "உலகம்",
        "color": "purple"
      }, {
        "name": "மருதநிலம்",
        "color": "purple"
      }, {
        "name": "பக்கம்",
        "color": "orange"
      }, {
        "name": "8 பதுமம்",
        "color": "blue"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "8 பதுமம்",
      "color": "maroon"
    }]
         };

  treeData = myJSON;

  var totalNodes = 0;
  var maxLabelLength = 0;

  var selectedNode = null;
  var draggingNode = null;

  var panSpeed = 200;
  var panBoundary = 0;

  var i = 0;
  var duration = 750;
  var root;

  var width = $(document).width();
  var height = $(document).height();

  var diameter = 700;

  var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([360, diameter / 2 - 120])
    .separation(function(a, b) {
      return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth;
    });

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function(d) {
      return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
    });

  root = treeData;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function sortTree() {
    tree.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.name.toLowerCase() < a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
    });
  }


  sortTree();

  function zoom() {
    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate
      (" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  }

  var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom()
       .scaleExtent([1, 1]).on("zoom", zoom);




  var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "overlay")

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  function expand(d) {
    if (d._children) {
      d.children = d._children;
      d.children.forEach(expand);
      d._children = null;
    }
  }

  function toggleChildren(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else if (d._children) {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    return d;
  }

  function click(d) {

    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
    d = toggleChildren(d);
    update(d);
    if (d.parent)
      d3.select("text").style("stroke", "red");
    return;
    update(d);
    if (!d.parent)
      d3.select("text").style("stroke", "black");
    return;
    update(d);

  }

  function update(source) {

    var levelWidth = [1];
    var childCount = function(level, n) {
      if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
        if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

        levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
        n.children.forEach(function(d) {
          childCount(level + 1, d);
        });
      }
    };
    childCount(0, root);
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
    links = tree.links(nodes);
    node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      //    .call(dragListener)
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on('click', click)

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "smallcircle")
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        var f = document.createElement("span");
        f.id = "hiddenText";
        f.style.display = 'hidden';
        f.style.padding = '0px';
        f.innerHTML = d.name;
        document.body.appendChild(f);
        textWidth = f.offsetWidth;
        var f1 = document.getElementById('hiddenText');
        f1.parentNode.removeChild(f1);
        return textWidth + 50;
      })
      .attr("overflow", "visible")
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("y", -50 / 2)
      .attr("x", -50)
      .append("xhtml:div").attr("class", "mainDiv")
      .html(function(d) {
        var htmlString = "";
        return htmlString;
      })

    nodeEnter.append("text")

    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("font", "10px serif")
      .style("opacity", 0.9)
      .style("fill-opacity", 0);


    nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr('class', 'ghostCircle')
      .attr("r", 30)
      .attr("opacity", 0)
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr('pointer-events', 'mouseover')
      .on("mouseover", function(node) {
        node.position = $(this).position();
        node.offset = $(this).offset();
        overCircle(node);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(node) {
        outCircle(node);
      });
    node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });


    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate
             (" + d.y + ")rotate(" + (-d.x + 90) + ")";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(360)translate(-8)";
      });

    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 0);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 0);


    var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
      })
    link.style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    })

    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
    link.style("stroke", function(d) {
        return d.target.color;
      })
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x0,
          y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      });


    link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);


    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x,
          y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      })
      .remove();


    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });
  }
  var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g").attr("transform",
   "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");


  root.children.forEach(function(child) {
    collapse(child);
  });

  update(root);
  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", width);
</script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: js fiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/6r550zne/7/    not shows anything because of the js file..i try to show result in fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/6qhxoaqx/1/ : corrected issues with display

Comment: @ mkaran thanks for the fiddle

Comment: i edited the code above..

Comment: i got the answer                                                                              function click(d) {
if (!d.children) 
  myJSON.children.forEach(collapse);

    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; 
    d = toggleChildren(d);
    update(d);

   
}